# Print newly created value for one specific string in the data frame (president's name)

Tags: r

I'm trying to pull the standardized height for a specific president by name (Ronald Reagan).

I'm currently having issues doing this because I unfortunately can't find the syntax for pulling a value for one president's name (I know this is likely very simple but I for some reason cant find it anywhere)

[image: Example]

Also if I call the dataset I only see the original columns, not the new one I created called "stand_height".

[image: Heights]

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Please don't provide screenshots of your code - just copy and paste the code directly into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
heights <- heights %>% mutate(stand_height = scale(mean(parse_number(height)))))
```

To pull the height for a specific president:

```
with(heights, height[Name == "Ronald Reaganz"])
```